# NSOperation dealloc not called when cancel operation

Tags: ios, nsoperation

I am using NSOperation in my application.
I am cancelling the previously executing operation when create another operation. But the previously created operation's dealloc method not calling when cancelling that operation.

Pls suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: nothing wrong with that unless `dealloc` **never** get called at all, cancel the operation doesn't means release it and release it doesn't means it should be deallocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just fine:

> [Responding to the Cancel Command](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)
>
> Once you add an operation to a queue, the operation is out of your
>   hands. The queue takes over and handles the scheduling of that task.
>   However, if you decide later that you do not want to execute the
>   operation after all—because the user pressed a cancel button in a
>   progress panel or quit the application, for example—you can cancel the
>   operation to prevent it from consuming CPU time needlessly. You do
>   this by calling the cancel method of the operation object itself or by
>   calling the cancelAllOperations method of the NSOperationQueue class.
>
> **Canceling an operation does not immediately force it to stop what it
>   is doing. Although respecting the value returned by the isCancelled is
>   expected of all operations**, your code must explicitly check the value
>   returned by this method and abort as needed. The default
>   implementation of NSOperation does include checks for cancellation.
>   For example, if you cancel an operation before its start method is
>   called, the start method exits without starting the task.

The `dealloc` method will be called when the retain count of the object gets to zero alas when no other object is using it.

Comment: But I need to dealloc the operation when it is cancelled. since it takes lot of memory.

Comment: You should never call dealloc, you should check for the isCancelled property periodically in your custom code and abort the operation, clean up your space, and abort as needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is that isFinished returns YES and isExecuting returns NO after cancelled. Otherwise the operation object will never be released.

Document says.

> In addition to simply exiting when an operation is cancelled, it is
>   also important that you move a cancelled operation to the appropriate
>   final state. Specifically, if you manage the values for the isFinished
>   and isExecuting properties yourself (perhaps because you are
>   implementing a concurrent operation), you must update those variables
>   accordingly. Specifically, you must change the value returned by
>   isFinished to YES and the value returned by isExecuting to NO. You
>   must make these changes even if the operation was cancelled before it
>   started executing.